# log4j.xml move rolling files to another directory/location?

Tags: java, log4j

My goal is whenever file `mylog.log` is rolled to `mylog.log.2015.08.05` this rolled file is also moved to another directory, so in the original directory there is always only `mylog.log`. Is this possible using `RollingFileAppender`? Or another appender from default `log4j` library?
it is necessary to **xml** format

```
<appender name="metrics" class="org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender">
    <param name="Threshold" value="INFO"/>
    <param name="File" value="${catalina.base}/logs/metrics.log"/>
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss}|%-5p|%t|%X{userName}|%X{req.userAgent}|%X{req.requestURL}|%X{req.queryString}|%C|%m%n"/>
    </layout>
</appender>
```

Comment: what do you mean by rolled file? Can you provide code?

Comment: now it seen like this <appender name="metrics" class="org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender"> <param name="Threshold" value="INFO"/> <param name="File" value="${catalina.base}/logs/metrics.log"/> <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout"> <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss}|%-5p|%t|%X{userName}|%X{req.userAgent}|%X{req.requestURL}|%X{req.query‌​String}|%C|%m%n"/> </layout> </appender>

Comment: please format your code so we can actually read it

Comment: i do it ) in my questions i format my code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change yours `fileName="logs/APP.log` and `filePattern="logs/sublogs/APP-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log"` so they points to different folders. You can even use patterns on your foldername like `filePattern="logs/sublogs-%d{yyyy-MM}/APP-%d{dd}.log"`.

Comment: This is a fairly elegant solution - I will certainly take note

Comment: If this works for you, please consider the following: http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: If a directory along the path in the `filePattern` field doesn't exist, will it be created?