# Can Log4j move rolled-over log files to another path?

Tags: log4j, log4j2

We're using Log4j's [rolling file appender](https://www.baeldung.com/java-logging-rolling-file-appenders) with [automatic compression](https://www.baeldung.com/java-logging-rolling-file-appenders#3-rolling-with-automatic-compression), but we'd like to move those compressed old logs off-machine to a NAS device to avoid the disk filling up.

Is there any way to do this automatically, ideally with Log4j appender config?

If not, has anyone done something like this before, and have recommendations?

Comment: It seems this question has already been [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31833760).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [log4j.xml move rolling files to another directory/location?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31833608/log4j-xml-move-rolling-files-to-another-directory-location)